# Why is SonarQube calculating coverage for files not in my lcov report? (Angular project)

Tags: angular, sonarqube

After running my tests and coverage, when I look at the generated reports (lcov) I see only two files being reported as 100% coverage each. These are the right files to be unit tested on my project.

However, after feeding this report to SonarQube, Sonar's coverage reports show several other files which all have 0% coverage.

I know I can exclude files via command line option and UI, but why do I have to do that if my report is already right?

Where is SonarQube looking to get a list of files to report coverage from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SonarQube is taking into account all project files to provide the project coverage metric. Because it’s a lie to display 100% coverage metric on a project containing source files not covered at all.

If test files are properly identified (sonar.tests, sonar.test.inclusions), and some specific files (like generated files) intentionally excluded (sonar.coverage.exclusions), then SonarQube project coverage metric is reliable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if SonarQube just imported the coverage report? Looks like duplicate work to me: set up the coverage report to only trck the files I want, and then set up SonarQube to only display data from the files I want.